# Bash or python, what is the most efficient to use pi's `GPIO`s?

Tags: python, bash

**TL;DR EDIT:** to clarify this question and why it's relevant to the PI:

what is the most efficient way in term of absolute time and energy (which I guess is more related to clock cycle) to now the value of a GPIO pin (let say for a one wire sensor but same with simple GPIO etc...)?

```
cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000123456/w1_slave
```

Or

```
f = open('/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000123456/w1_slave', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()                                   # read the device details
print(lines)
```

**Original question below:**

It's been some time that I am playing around with some raspberries and I usually  do whatever I want with simple bash scripts, mainly because I am used and feel comfortable with `ssh`/`awk`/`sed`/`grep`... But I may be wrong doing so.

Thus, I was wondering if there are any reasons to use python , other than that it as "A large community supports and uses the Python language as it is easy to learn and code".

For example, to read a sensor or activate a GPIO I use to `cat` and `echo` the files in `/sys/devices/` or `/sys/class/gpio/`. But maybe the python libraries are better optimised to do so?

That maybe a naive question but I am curious and willing to change my habits if they are bad (and more if it can save a few CPU calls and energy).

Comment: Why just these two?  If you're worried about efficiency, why not open it up? Just curious because I would have said "neither".

Comment: Yes you right. Thing is that I didn't want to have to compile C each time test some sensors and went to send and receive the output of to a server etc... Bash and python sounded like the easiest way to get thing done quickly. Thus was wondering if one is better than the other. You may be right and they may be both as bad!

Comment: The Pi is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I think the Pi is relevant to this question insofar as the access to the GPIO pins is (or at least could be thought to be) specific to the Pi, not the scripting. @joan

Comment: The question of which if either is more efficient for gpio is relevent to the pi in my opinion. But you'd have to define a metric to decide efficiency anyway. More efficient in programmer time or clock cycles would be different questions. And since the pi doesn't have especially fast gpio compared to other options, maybe the programmer time is more relevant. And for you if you're comfortable with the shell, that's probably better for you.

Comment: Thanks for you comment @T.M. Indeed my question came indeed from the fact that using `echo` or `cat` on gpio and sensors I noticed some delay. I thought it may be a problem of implementation and that python gpio/sensors libraies may accelerate that. For what I get from your comment this maybe more a hardware problem? Thus the last part of your answer totally makes sens.

Comment: I think that any answer to this question is going to be too opinion based to be useful. There is no single definition of *efficient* because it means different things to different people - as a predominantly 'C' coder I am more likely to reach for my `gcc` compiler than knocking up a `bash` script but both have their pros and cons - as does python (once you remember that indentation is important for that coding system 8-0 ...)

Comment: I added an sentence that I think explian bette rwhat I mean by " efficient"